# How to access value of an abstract method in a different class?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

`AbstractInputFile` is an abstract class and has the following code below:

```
public abstract class AbstractInputFile {

    static final public int MIN_BILLING_CYCLE = 1;
    static final public int MAX_BILLING_CYCLE = 12;

    private File file;

    public AbstractInputFile() {

    }

    public abstract List<Request> readFile() throws IOException, BarsException;

    public File getFile() {

        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

`CSVInputFileImpl` is a subclass of `AbstractInputFile`, thus inheriting the readFile() method. What it does is it reads the contents of a csv file using a buffered reader, stores it in an arraylist, and returns it.

```
    public List<Request> readFile() throws IOException, BarsException {
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        
        String line = "";

        //READ CSV FILE
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFile()));
            int row = 1;
            int index = 0;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(",", 3);

                //Validate if billing cycle ranges 1-12
                try {
                    int billingCycle = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);

                    if(billingCycle <= MAX_BILLING_CYCLE && billingCycle >= MIN_BILLING_CYCLE) {
                        request.setBillingCycle(billingCycle);

                    } else {
                        log.error(BILLING_CYCLE_NOT_ON_RANGE +  row);
                        throw new BarsException(BILLING_CYCLE_NOT_ON_RANGE +  row);
                    }

                } catch (BarsException e) {
                    log.error(INVALID_BILLING_CYCLE + row);
                    throw new BarsException(INVALID_BILLING_CYCLE + row);
                }


                //Validate start date
                try {
                    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(data[1], formatter);
                    request.setStartDate(startDate);

                } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                    log.error(INVALID_START_DATE_FORMAT + row);
                    throw new BarsException(INVALID_START_DATE_FORMAT + row);
                }


                //Validate end date
                try {
                    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(data[2], formatter);
                    request.setStartDate(endDate);

                } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                    log.error(INVALID_END_DATE_FORMAT + row);
                    throw new BarsException(INVALID_END_DATE_FORMAT + row);
                }

                row++;


                //Add the requests to array list created previously
                requests.add(index,new Request(request.getBillingCycle(), request.getStartDate(), request.getEndDate()));
                index++;

           }

        //Validate if file exists
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new BarsException(NO_SUPPORTED_FILE);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(PATH_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
        }

        return requests;
    }
```

In another public class `FileProcessor`, I am instructed to get the array list using `List<Request> requests = abstractInputFile.readFile();` but is unable to do so because I am getting the error `Non-static method 'readFile()' cannot be referenced from a static context`.

```
    public List<Request> execute(File file) throws BarsException {

        InputFileFactory fact = InputFileFactory.getInstance();

        try {
            fact.getInputFile(file);
        } catch (BarsException e) {
            throw new BarsException(NO_SUPPORTED_FILE);
        }

        List<Request> requests = AbstractInputFile.readFile();

        return requests;

    }
```

My question is: How will I be able to retrieve the arraylist and return it in the `execute(file)` method? There might be a lot more errors in other areas of the code and logic but I'd appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: `readFile()` is instance method. Why exactly are you trying to invoke it as a static one?

Comment: So long as InputFileFactory,getInstance() works and returns an instance of a concrete subclass, it looks like `List<Request> requests = AbstractInputFile.readFile();` should be `List<Request> requests = fact.readFile();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, AbstractInputFile.readFile() can't be called for 2 reasons:  readFile() in the AbstractInputFile class is abstract, and it is an instance method.

From what you wrote here, you implement the readFile() method in the subclass, CSVInputFileImpl. Therefore, in this case, your readFile() calls should be based on THIS class, not AbstractInputFile. However, this is still classified as an instance method, meaning you need to first create an instance of CSVInputFileImpl before you can call readFile(). I would correct the code like this (I'm making assumptions that the CSVInputFileImpl class is structured the same as AbstractInputFile, but make sure the file instance var is set):

```
CSVInputFileImpl csvInputFileImpl = new CSVInputFileImpl();
csvInputFileImpl.setFile(file);
List<Request> requests = csvInputFileImpl.readFile();
return requests;
```